# Is it possible to request a file from the server directly from html img tag src and loaad it with jwt authentication header?

Tags: angular, http, authentication, get, jwt

I'm trying to request the server to send a file directly from the src in an html img tag instead of sending a get request via Angular HttpClient (I'm using HttpClient anywhere else in the app).
The problem is that the files endpoint in the server is protected with AuthGuard - JWT strategy, meaning that every request have to contain a valid token in the header to get a response, and by trying to get a file directly from the src in the img html tag there will always be an error sent back since the token was never assigned to the headers request.

I'm using an AuthInterceptor that implements HttpInterceptor to set the token on the header but this kind of requests doesn't get there.

The request is not passing through the interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const idToken = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (idToken) {
      const cloned = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 
     idToken),
       })
      return next.handle(cloned)
    } else {
      return next.handle(req)
    }
  }
}
```

This is the way I'm trying to get the image:

```
<img src="serverhost:port/api/document/:imageId" />
```

And obviously I get 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: may i ask why u wanna do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to setup the headers of the get request the browser executes.
A solution for that can be usage of signed URL. The meaning is that a temporary authentication token will be part of the URL itself.